# How to get the JFrame object of which content is included?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

```
    class MyPanel extends JPanel{
        MyPanel(){
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if(getBackground() == Color.white)
                        setBackground(Color.black);
                    else
                        setBackground(Color.white);
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to change not panel_background but frame_background.
Would you tell me how to do this? thank you.

Comment: If you know that the current JPanel is held by a JFrame (and not say a JDialog), then do `JFrame currentFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(MyPanel.this);` as per the duplicate answer

Comment: I heartily thank you.

Comment: I couldn't tell by searching alone. Thank for your contribute, now I know about function, getWindowAncestor. It is first activity in asking. Remembering your good deed, I also promise to do good for others. :D